# Tag not fired gtm based on form element

Tags: google-tag-manager

The form element is not being recognised and thus the tag is not being fired (see images).
There is no click ID, or click class that I can use.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpjOG.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5HDu.png)

I tried using different parts of the form element to see if it would fire the tag, without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use "contains" with html elements. Use "matches CSS selector" instead.

You can keep the value the same. It's a selector.